# syntax for outputting a 2d vector

Tags: c++, vector

Say if I have a 2d vector of Int:

```
vector <vector<Int> > myV;
```

Then I define 2 variables:

```
int rows; //number of vectors in myV. This is the my y(vertical) index.
int columns; //number of elements in one vector within myV. x index.
```

I want to know when I output myV like a rectangle: iterate through myV[something][something], which variable should be in the left bracket, and which should be right? I just want the variables to fit perfectly into my intention.

I also wrote a test code, but it has segmentation fault that I haven't figured out why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  vector<vector<int> > myV;

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
          myV[i][j] = j;
  }
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        cout << myV[i][j] << " ";
    cout << endl;}
}
```

Comment: unrelated tactical note: A really small 2D structure like that like that is going to suffer greatly from a lack of spatial locality because that's not one `vector`, it's actually 4 `vector`s and they could be scattered in memory. If you have one or two and you use it rarely, who cares? But if you are dong a lot of manipulation of 3x3 matrices, you're going for spend a lot of time waiting for cache. Silly as it sounds, you're better of making 1 `vector` of size 9 and do the indexing yourself with `row * num_columns + column`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is because you haven't allocated any memory for your vector. Change the declaration of the vector to:

```
vector<vector<int>> myV(3, vector<int>(3));
```

On a side note, I would even consider storing your array in one dimension (i.e `std::vector<int> myV(9);`) and compute indexes for multidimensional use using a function `getIndex`, which could be implemented as:

```
inline std::vector<int>::size_type getIndex(int numCols, int i, int j)
{
    return i * numCols + j;
}
```

Usage of this function may look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++i)
    {
        myV[getIndex(3, i, j)] = /* Value */;
    }
}
```

This would avoid the large use of memory a multidimensional vector needs, and would allow usage in pretty much the same way.

Here is some [further reading](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/17108/#msg85594) for more information on why one should use 1d arrays for representing 2d arrays.